# Angular 10 @Input by reference

Tags: angular

Im having problem to get value change from a component property.
In this simple example, I have an ngFor that create instance of TextField Component passing fields[i].value as property.
I value has a default, its correctly printed on input but the changes are not reflected on the original model.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields.all(); let i = index;">
                        <dynamic-text-field

                            [id]        = "field.name"
                            [name]      = "field.name"
                            [label]     = "field.label"
                            [note]      = "field.translate_help"
                            [(val)]     = "fields[i].value"
                        >

                        </dynamic-text-field>
 </ng-container>


export class TextField
{

    @Input() id         : string = "";
    @Input() name       : string = "";
    @Input() note       : string = "";
    @Input() label      : string = "";
    @Input() val        : string = null;

    [...]
}

<mat-label translate> {{ label | translate }} </mat-label>
<input  matInput placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="val" name="{{name}}" />
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't just do [(val)]="field.value"?

Comment: Because during ngfor you have to reference the current iteration model otherwise you are passing the last element to every component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing thats because an `@Input` is not really a two-way binding.
In addition, it looks like your `fields[i].value` is a primitive (`string`).

This might be a workaround that is not ideal, but you can try passing an object as `val` and then, in your `TextField` component, refer to the value by something like `[(ngModel)]="val.value"`. That way, `val` is an object, so it's passed by the reference to a child component - any updates to the model will be available in the parent component.

The other way could be to pass a callback function to the child component that you'd call on model update - something like:

```
                        <dynamic-text-field

                            [id]        = "field.name"
                            [name]      = "field.name"
                            [label]     = "field.label"
                            [note]      = "field.translate_help"
                            [val]       = "fields[i].value"
                            (valueChange)="onValueChange($event)"
                        >

                        </dynamic-text-field>
```

with:

```
<mat-label translate> {{ label | translate }} </mat-label>
<input  matInput placeholder="" [ngModel]="val" (change)="valueChange.emit($event.value)" name="{{name}}" />
```

with:

```
export class TextField
{

    @Input() id         : string = "";
    @Input() name       : string = "";
    @Input() note       : string = "";
    @Input() label      : string = "";
    @Input() val        : string = null;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    [...]
}
```

and then trigger whatever logic you need in the parent's `onValueChange` method

Comment: I would agree with this answer because the original TextField component has no @Output() declared, then you cannot expect a twoway bind in the ng-container. So the mapInput supports the binding but TextField does not.

This can all be read @ https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

Comment: Thank you. Im using a JustString model instead of privimite and it works perfectly